# Django 4: How to modify MultiPolygonField from nullable to not-null

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, geodjango, django-4.0

I am trying to convert my MultiPolygonField field from this:

```
multipolygon = MultiPolygonField(null=True)
```

to this:

```
multipolygon = MultiPolygonField(null=False)
```

It looks simple, so I execute "makemigrations" and I get the usual message warning that the database needs something to populate existing rows (I confirmed that there is no row in my database with that field being null):

Whether I choose option 1:

> 1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows
>    with a null value for this column)

And set the following as default:

```
'SRID=3857;POINT(0.0 0.0)'
```

or option 2:

> 2. Ignore for now. Existing rows that contain NULL values will have to
>    be handled manually, for example with a RunPython or RunSQL operation

I get the following error when I execute "migrate":

> ValueError: Cannot alter field borders.Border.multipolygon into
> borders.Border.multipolygon - they do not properly define db_type (are
> you using a badly-written custom field?)

I have been able to make that same change with other simpler field types without any issue. How to do this with MultiPolygonFields?
I am using Django 4 and sqlite 3.31, in case that matters.

Comment: I have never worked with `MultiPolygonField` but the default you declared does not look like the "normal" input of the MultiPolygonField... As of my understanding you should open `python manage.py shell`, then import MultiPolygon, then create one MultiPolygon-Object. Most likely you can not create it with `MultiPolygon("SRID=3857;POINT(0.0 0.0)")`. Figure out what you have to input there to create that object. Then look up its __repr__ or __str__ function and take that as the default for your migration.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help @Tarquinius. I can create MultiPolygonField  with the following code: from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry then GEOSGeometry('SRID=4326;POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))'). I confirmed I can assign that to my MultiPolygonField and persist to the database without any issue. Unfortunately copying the string representation of that ('SRID=4326;POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))') to the prompt after I choose the option 1 leads me to the same error that I wrote in my first question.

Comment: Actually, I confirmed that If I add I new MultiPolygonField  (Instead of modifying, as I am trying) I can use an empty string '' as default value without any issue. That approach does not work in the case of modifying the field

Comment: That does not make sense to me, since you are inserting a POINT to a MultiPolygonField. So I do not know why that assignment is working for you in the shell, because your input does not anywhere near like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#multipolygon). Also try to not specify the srid. It should be populated with a default then. Option 2 needs you to actually modify the already existing fields by hand via the shell. If you don't do it before `migrate` you get that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I finally "solved" the issue (not exactly solved, but I found a longer way to get the same results):

I divided the migration in 6 steps:

1. I created a new field "multipolygon_new"
2. I copied data from my initial field "multipolygon" to the new one I just created "multipolygon_new"
3. I deleted my initial field, "multipolygon"
4. I created "multipolygon" again, but being not-null
5. I copied data from "multipolygon_new" to ""multipolygon"
6. I deleted "multipolygon_new"

For steps 2 and 5 used the following command to create a custom migration:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty yourappname
```

and then I modified the migration file to execute my custom copy query:

```
migrations.RunSQL(
    sql=[("UPDATE mytable ......", ],
)
```

for the other steps I used the usual makemigrations command.